# Why can't I smash these 2 fractured objects together?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have 2 objects that have been fractured, but for some reason I can't apply keyframes.  I tried testing animating a cube to see if there were larger problems with settings but that worked fine.  Could anyone shed some light on why this might be happening?

Thanks

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Here's the .blend:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps try parenting each each fragment to a single empty (Therefore the empty controls the whole object), then animating the empty, and just before the objects collide, animate the fragments parenting so that they are in control of themselves just before collision. Does that make sense?

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Comment: I can't remember since it was years ago lol, but I think now I would simply use the Fracture Modifier...back then I was using cell fracture

Comment: Actually I'd somehow got into 'Unanswered Questions' but asked anyway. :)  I tried using Cell fracture in some jobs but always came up against the animation wanting to start at frame 1 so I ended up adopting the Explode modifier and adding my own 3D shrapnel from one or more additional emitters.  It eliminated the need to determine the fractures beforehand and yet still appear to be breaking up into recognisable components, just by designing those as emitter objects.  Works well for me.  Cheers...

Answer (score 1):

Check the "Animated" box in your physics settings. As it's name states, it will allow you to animate the objects with keyframes.

Comment: Hm it seems to work for individual fragments but not the whole object when I copy from active...